# Is it possible to set up two mosquitto brokers on the same machine with different access to them?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Is it possible to set up two brokers on the same machine with different access to them? Or one broker - one machine, the second - the second?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it is possible. You will want to point each instance at a different configuration files (`-c` / `--config-file` command line option) and ensure that the configuration files do not have `listener`'s on the same the same port.

The different instances will be independent (so something with a connection to one broker will not receive any messages published to a second broker unless you establish a bridge between them).